# Calculating heat from braking

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, friction

I am given a locomotive with a mass of 45 tonnes that's moving with a constant speed of $60 km/h$ on a 4‰ slope. It brakes and it's speed becomes 0 after 200 meters. How do I find the heat obtained trough friction while braking?

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: What amount of the friction is turned into heat? All of it? Just a part?

Comment: But have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes. I calculated friction as the change in kinetic energy between the 2 stated divides by the braking distance so from my calculations that would be 4.05 x 10^5.

Comment: This question is pretty clear. I don't agree with the close votes. They are asking about the concept of heat generation from friction, in the application of locomotives. Mind that this is an active area of research (tribology) and thus question has merit IMHO.

Comment: Is the train going uphill or downhill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation seems wrong: but you just give a number without units.  All the kinetic energy goes to heat energy + potential energy , the potential energy is about 36kJ the loss of kinetic energy is 6250kJ so the 36kJ more going down or less going up don't matter.